# WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 : java.sql.SQLException : Total number of Available connections are less than the total number of closed connections:

Tags: sql, wso2, esb, sqlexception

java.sql.SQLException : Total number of Available connections are less than the total number of closed connections:

I am having little troubles with deploying a WSO2 ESB clustered environment composed with a manager instance, two worker instances and a shared database on a separated server. Each instance is on a Virtual box VM.
I keep getting  the following exception each time I run the servers:

```
    [2017-08-01 02:07:34,827] ERROR - RegistryUtils Failed to construct the connectionId.
    java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:86)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.getConnectionId(RegistryUtils.java:194)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.getConnectionId(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1133)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.commit(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1212)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.commitTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:159)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.commitTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:452)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:658)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.resourceExists(CacheBackedRegistry.java:376)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExistsInternal(UserRegistry.java:774)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$800(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:757)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.MediaTypesUtils.getResourceMediaTypeMappings(MediaTypesUtils.java:342)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.setupMediaTypes(RegistryUtils.java:1145)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:533)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
    [2017-08-01 02:07:34,829] ERROR - RegistryUtils Failed to construct the connectionId.
    java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:86)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.getConnectionId(RegistryUtils.java:194)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.getConnectionId(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1133)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.commit(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1238)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.commitTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:159)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.commitTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:452)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:658)

        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
    [2017-08-01 02:07:35,064] ERROR - TransactionManager Failed to close transaction.
    java.sql.SQLException: Total number of available connections are less than the total number of closed connections
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.close(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1360)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.endTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.commitTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:167)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.commitTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:452)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:658)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.resourceExists(CacheBackedRegistry.java:376)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExistsInternal(UserRegistry.java:774)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$800(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:757)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.systemResourceShouldBeAdded(RegistryUtils.java:640)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.addUserProfileCollection(RegistryUtils.java:994)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:535)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
    [2017-08-01 02:07:35,076] ERROR - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Failed to activate Registry Core bundle 
    org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to close transaction.
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.endTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:183)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.commitTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:167)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.commitTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:452)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:658)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.resourceExists(CacheBackedRegistry.java:376)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExistsInternal(UserRegistry.java:774)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$800(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:757)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$9.run(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:754)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.systemResourceShouldBeAdded(RegistryUtils.java:640)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.addUserProfileCollection(RegistryUtils.java:994)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:535)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Total number of available connections are less than the total number of closed connections
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDatabaseTransaction$ManagedRegistryConnection.close(JDBCDatabaseTransaction.java:1360)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.endTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:178)
        ... 51 more
    [2017-08-01 02:07:35,153]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
    [2017-08-01 02:07:45,824]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
```

I literally followed the tutorial on this link
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+ESB+4.9.0#ClusteringESB4.9.0-Settingupthedatabases

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Sounds to me like connection problem: `PooledConnection has already been closed.`. Are you sure the connection between the VM and the DB is okay?

Comment: Yes I could remotely access the database from my VM

Answer (score 0):

This error[1] can be caused when there is an issue in the registry mounting configuration. So, please double check the mounting configuration available in your registry.xml file. Specially `currentDBConfig` and `dbConfig`  values.

[1]. `Total number of available connections are less than the total number of closed connections`